# Find the UMVUE for $\mu ^{2}$ by assuming $\sigma ^{2}$ is unknown.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Suppose that $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ is a random sample from normal$(\mu, σ^2)$.

Find the UMVUE for $\mu ^{2}$ by assuming $\sigma ^{2}$ is unknown.

**My approach:**

The distribution of the sample mean, namely $$\bar X\sim\mathcal N\left(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\right)$$

If $\sigma$ is known, a complete sufficient statistic for $\mu$ is $$\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \quad(\text{ and hence }\bar X)$$

Now,

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(\bar X)&=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}
\\\implies E(\bar X^2)&=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}+\mu^2
\end{align}

That is, $$E\left(\bar X^2-\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\right)=\mu^2 $$

By Lehmann-Scheffe, $$\bar X^2-\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$$ is the UMVUE of $\mu^2$ when $\sigma^2$ is known.

**My problem is how do I show the case where $\sigma^2$ is unknown?**

Comment: You mean sample from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$? For $\sigma$ unknown, find an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$ based on a complete sufficient statistic.

Comment: I made a correction concerning $\mu$. I know $S^2$ is complete sufficient statistic for $\sigma^2$. But what do I do from there?

Comment: Yes... I apologize for leaving out essential information.

Comment: Then $(\bar X,S^2)$ is complete sufficient and $S^2$ is unbiased for $\sigma^2$. That's all you need.

Comment: No.... I need the UMVUE of $\mu^2$ instead.

Comment: Can you not write $E(\bar X^2-\sigma^2/n)=E(\bar X^2-S^2/n)$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92844/discussion-between-lady-and-stubbornatom).